Problem with highlighting first row and column of a table
I try to create the following table.

After a lot of trial and error I thought that I succeeded.
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan} $n$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}Reste de $2^n \pmod{5}$} &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}Reste de $3^n \pmod{5}$} &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{LightCyan}Reste de $2^n + 3^n \pmod{5}$} &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Nevertheless, I think that the highlighting covers the lines.

How to overcome this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

If I scale the PDF view all lines are shown. So in your case, it seems to be more an issue of the PDF viewer. However, best support for tables with lines and color is IMHO in package tabularray.

You could use the tabularray package for such tables. It makes it very easy to change the colour for specific rows and columns:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  vlines,hlines,
  column{1}={LightCyan,halign=l},
  row{1}={halign=c,LightCyan}
}
$n$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
Reste de $2^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
Reste de $3^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
Reste de $2^n + 3^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Missing lines or lines with not equal line width are often the result of the scaling in the PDF viewer. So you should either increase the size of the view or print it. If I test your code, I cannot see a problem with scale 100% or 200%. Nevertheless I would use the main column alignment for the column specification and use the different only in in the one column of the table header:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightCyan}}l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightCyan}\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$n$} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\hline
Reste de $2^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
Reste de $3^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
Reste de $2^n + 3^n \pmod{5}$ &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


But to be honest, I would always prefer a tabularray solution.
